# Como remapear una tecla con c++

Tags: c++, linux, windows, eventos, keypressevent

Hola tengo que hacer un trabajo sobre remapear teclas del teclado con c++, y simular el pulsado de estas.
Ejemplo: pulso 'a'  y me escribe 'e'

Tengo este codigo:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char key;

    for (;;)
    {
        for (key = 8; key < 222; key++)
        {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(key) == -32767)
            {
                /* si la tecla esta entre A y Z */
                /* Si la tecla shift no esta activa, la tecla es minuscula entonces entra */
                if ((key > 64) && (key < 91) && !(GetAsyncKeyState(0x10)))
                {
                    key += 32;

                    switch (key)
                    { /* CON ESTE SWITCH CONTROLO POR CADA TECLA (ASCI) QUE HACER */

                    case 97: /* el 97 corresponde a la tecla a  */

                        /* SIMULO PULSAR LA TECLA e */
                        keybd_event(0x45, /* AQUI VA LA TECLA QUE SE VA A SIMULAR */
                                    0x45, /* ESTO NO SE PARA QUE SIRVE PERO SIEMPRE PONGO LA TECLA QUE SIMULO */
                                    KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | 0,
                                    0);

                        /* SIMULO SOLTAR LA TECLA E */
                        keybd_event(0x45,
                                    0x45,
                                    KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,
                                    0);
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Consigo ir registrando con un bucle infinito los eventos de teclado generados y tratarlos para saber si es de una tecla o de otra, en el ejemplo del código trato solo la tecla 'a' en minúscula, y si se cumple genero dos eventos de teclado uno de pulsar y otro de soltar la tecla 'e'.

El problema lo tengo que tambien se escribe la tecla por defecto, en este caso al pulsar la 'a' escribe 'ae'.

Lo que necesito es cancelar el evento original creado por la tecla a para que esta no se muestre y solo se muestre la 'e'.

tiene que ser en c++, si se os ocurre alguna librería de gestión de pulsaciones, eventos de teclado, macros y remapeo de teclas etc, que evite codificar todas las configuraciones y métodos de 0 también me vendría bien, gracias.

Comment: Lo suyo es usar una librería si compilas para Windows y otra si compilas para Linux. ¿No te parece?

Comment: La pregunta podría ser más simple: "¿Cómo hacer un programa multiplataforma?" En C++ puedes programar clases abstractas que definan un comportamiento agnóstico. Creas clases que lo implementen para el sistema operativo correspondiente y en tiempo de compilación decides cuál implementación usar.

Comment: @MauricioContreras tambien puedo hacer eso, el problema volveria a tener en windows al usar la libreria winuser.h que no encuentro la manera de conseguir que no se escriba la tecla real pulsada, delante de la que simulo, osea cancelar ese evento por defecto

Comment: @MauricioContreras quieres que deje un fracmento de codigo que muestre el sistema que uso para detectar los eventos de teclas que pulsa el teclado y como simulo un evento dependiendo de cual ha sido la tecla pulsada ?

Comment: Deberías poner lo que tienes hecho y así tener un punto de partida para ver la duda concreta.

Comment: @user3733164 eh editado la pregunta con un enunciado mas facil y especificando mas el problema que tengo y adjuntando codigo, gracias

Comment: Ya hiciste una pregunta similar. https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/531121/169744 y esto te podría ser útil https://stackoverflow.com/a/6899073/13419694

Answer (score 1):

Lo eh conseguido adjunto el codigo por si en un futuro ayuda a alguien

```
// Hacer un ejecutable realmente pequeño
#pragma comment(linker,"/ENTRY:main") // Establecer punto de entrada

// Combina todas las secciones predeterminadas en la sección .text (código).
#pragma comment(linker,"/MERGE:.rdata=.data")
#pragma comment(linker,"/MERGE:.text=.data")

#pragma comment(lib, "msvcrt.lib")

#if (_MSC_VER < 1300) // _MSC_VER es una macro en la que esta definida la version del copilador que esta utilizando
    #pragma comment(linker,"/IGNORE:4078")
    #pragma comment(linker,"/OPT:NOWIN98")
#endif

#pragma comment(linker, "/FILEALIGN:0x200")

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define VC_EXTRALEAN

#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
BOOL WINAPI ConsoleEventHandler(DWORD dwCtrlType); // para una salida elegante
DWORD dwMainThread = 0; // porque aparentemente el hilo del controlador de eventos de la consola para Ctrl+C es diferente del hilo principal

int main(int args, char* argv[])
{
    const char message[] =
        "conseguido";

    DWORD count = 0;
    HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    WriteConsoleA(hStdOut, message, sizeof(message)-2, &count, NULL);

    if (!SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ConsoleEventHandler, TRUE))
        return -1;

    dwMainThread = GetCurrentThreadId();

    // Recuperar la instancia de aplicaciones
    HINSTANCE appInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
 
    // Adjuntar gancho de teclado global para capturar pulsaciones de teclas
    HHOOK hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, appInstance, 0);
    if (!hHook)
        return -2;

    MSG msg; //mensajes de consola

    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    // limpiar
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ConsoleEventHandler, FALSE);

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *pKeyBoard = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *)lParam;

    switch( pKeyBoard->vkCode )
    {
    case 0x41: /* VK_CAPITAL  A*/
        {
            switch (wParam)
            {
            case WM_KEYDOWN:
                keybd_event(0x45, 0x8e, 0, 0);
                return 1;
            case WM_KEYUP:
                keybd_event(0x45, 0x8e, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
                return 1;
            }
        }
        
        default:
            return CallNextHookEx( NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam );
    }

    return 0;
}


BOOL WINAPI ConsoleEventHandler(DWORD dwCtrlType)
{
    switch(dwCtrlType)
    {
        case CTRL_C_EVENT:
        case CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT:
            PostThreadMessage(dwMainThread, WM_QUIT, NULL, NULL);
            return TRUE;

        default:
            return FALSE;
    }
}
```